# What are the mathematical equations for these three particular spirals of modulo three groups squared

Tags: geometry

Continuing from my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4461125/why-do-perfect-squares-in-pythagorean-spirals-generate-triple-spiral-pattern), I want to know what is the equations of the three continuous curves these three discrete sets of vertices are approaching, so that I can calculate the intersections of them with a regular polygon whose center is at the origin (including circles, which is a regular polygon with infinite number of sides).

I have managed to plot the three spirals directly.

With polylines:

[image]

With continuous curves:

[image]

With data:

[image]

Raw data:

```
{
    'arm_0': {
        0: (1, 0),
        9: (-1.497112501918127, -2.7854360801498306),
        36: (-4.98458532826389, -3.4862457035120658),
        81: (-8.74302530802115, -2.3578609932100782),
        144: (-12.02537661686118, 0.6247537295991847),
        225: (-14.09884120422741, 5.217535500404312),
        324: (-14.34564731859593, 10.917985299974568),
        441: (-12.349124780077803, 17.014673583882512),
        576: (-7.958753928923706, 22.66402956005053),
        729: (-1.3269058233345064, 26.985909674050397),
        900: (7.087529794682105, 29.16790910246232),
        1089: (16.550145885300477, 28.56733573813433),
        1296: (26.114611762933436, 24.799738959740765),
        1521: (34.713383531937104, 17.80396033933651),
        1764: (41.26708260884942, 7.875778879224264),
        2025: (44.80188956600656, -4.334823100820575),
        2304: (44.56309906885234, -17.86421566651363),
        2601: (40.11292366103734, -31.51116239309276),
        2916: (31.40175329803707, -43.94234734068402),
        3249: (18.804295543302523, -53.81819830800998),
        3600: (3.115153314278089, -59.92742126797002),
        3969: (-14.497833116609144, -61.31731268510724)
    },
    'arm_1': {
        1: (1, 1),
        16: (4.074022642113989, -0.6343023817884941),
        49: (5.996732853004965, -3.7468913901647802),
        100: (6.317606591629188, -7.815871477538745),
        169: (4.7131951151331055, -12.156717970187723),
        256: (1.119993543058584, -15.992048476149222),
        361: (-4.240153608700732, -18.547805729374634),
        484: (-10.871585332769126, -19.152248754449722),
        625: (-18.049465629543615, -17.326765147826205),
        784: (-24.89305639538484, -12.858294727381011),
        961: (-30.460426219812412, -5.844863942588621),
        1156: (-33.85505726799531, 3.2916709101562596),
        1369: (-34.33332875841694, 13.828323700524258),
        1600: (-31.401435769992876, 24.798182021733684),
        1849: (-24.891018197164836, 35.07758847338917),
        2116: (-15.00458268776432, 43.495545730179025),
        2401: (-2.3245484507820535, 48.95504544477546),
        2704: (12.216809821981386, 50.554421743044585),
        3025: (27.405429449901824, 47.69635663933425),
        3364: (41.846609373180776, 40.17289240232254),
        3721: (54.090831029320185, 28.216697158912027)
    },
    'arm_2': {
        4: (-1.6308097207961918, 1.5298560894922917),
        25: (-1.1072688801027475, 4.977344234343855),
        64: (1.2030383665443862, 7.971994649309683),
        121: (5.025225140018225, 9.83601099491705),
        196: (9.852134360350037, 9.996771906251038),
        289: (14.986552417661628, 8.08722737609624),
        400: (19.62024563990485, 4.005741008826664),
        529: (22.929824939835186, -2.055025116273555),
        676: (24.17841787504091, -9.612705605598585),
        841: (22.812021983982696, -17.93353431430349),
        1024: (18.5398249709077, -26.101243074767932),
        1225: (11.389197702942742, -33.11021255871532),
        1444: (1.7284388687767098, -37.97383966728841),
        1681: (-9.746528349261542, -39.83723365316765),
        1936: (-22.06172637665742, -38.08254494229001),
        2209: (-34.047479396609724, -32.41556951123166),
        2500: (-44.44661556205796, -22.923751112736397),
        2809: (-52.03869920832135, -10.098207004508943),
        3136: (-55.76847825882021, 5.1842870961775915),
        3481: (-54.86582728961407, 21.719599347741152),
        3844: (-48.944773389840655, 38.07110660090342)
    }
}
```

[Code](https://github.com/Estrangeling/Eleyi/blob/main/pythagorean_spiral.py)

What are the equations?

---

Well, the vertices are generated like this: you start at point (1, 0) and (1, 1), the points are numbered 0 and 1 respectively.

Then you connect the two points plus the origin to form a right triangle with two of the angles being 45°, the hypotenuse of said right triangle is the square root of two.

Then you use the previous hypotenuse as one of the legs of a new right triangle, the other leg is one, the triangle is on top (in the counterclockwise direction) of the previous triangle, you take the vertex of the new triangle that is neither the origin nor already numbered, in this iteration the vertex is (0.29289321881345254, 1.7071067811865475), you number it two, the hypotenuse of the triangle of this iteration is the square root of three.

Then you take that root three hypotenuse as one of the legs of a new right triangle, the other leg still being one, you construct the triangle counterclockwise, you take the vertex that is neither the origin nor already numbered, here it is (-0.6927053408400363, 1.87620875991231), you number it three, the hypotenuse of this triangle is two (root four), you construct a new triangle... And so on, and so forth.

Then you filter out the vertices whose number is not perfect squares, leaving only vertices whose indices are perfect squares.

The above is how the vertices are generated.

I then grouped the vertices into three groups, based on their square roots modulo three (all possible values: 0, 1, 2), and connected all points in each group.

Comment: @runway44 The vertices are generated programmatically using  a Python script I wrote that I shared in the question body (the code link), according to the rules of Pythagorean spiral, the link to the previous question is also present in the question body...

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the constant $c\approx -2.15778$ by

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\Big)=2\sqrt{n}+c+o(1). $$

All vertices are $(r,\theta)=(\sqrt{n},2\sqrt{n}+c)$ up to $o(1)$ error. If we define $n=(3k+s)^2$, where $s$ is one of the remainders $0,1,2$ mod $3$, this becomes $(3k+s,6k+2s+c)$.

The thing is, if we fix $s$, then each time we increment $k$ the point winds almost all the way around, which means there is an alternate (more natural to the eye) interpretation of the points as going around backwards. In order for our formula to reflect this, we want to subtract $2\pi$ from the angle each time we increment $k$, or in other words subtract $2\pi k$ from the angle in this formula:

$$ (r,\theta)=\big(\,3k+s,\,(6-2\pi)k+(2s+c)\,\big) $$

Notice $6-2\pi$ is small and negative; the spirals go around backwards slowly. If we solve for $k$ in terms of $\theta$ and then substitute into the formula for $k$ we get the three equations

$$ r=3\,\frac{\theta-(2s+c)}{6-2\pi}+s, \qquad \theta<0, \quad s=0,1,2. $$

(Note adding $3$ to $s$ amounts to subtracting $2\pi$ from $\theta$.)